# Does scala affect AspectJ/Spring AOP at all? I'm having a thread locking problem when running tests when an @Configurable is being called

Tags: spring, scala, locking, aop, aspectj

I have a strange problem where when I run my tests using maven, it locks whenever a test method calls into an object with an annotation @Configurable. I can run the tests fine in IDEA using the AspectJ Weaver plugin (remarkably), but I cannot do it with maven (whether I execute them in IDEA or just in a terminal).

Even weirder, if I press ctrl-c, it does not kill the process. It just keeps a 500meg process in memory for eternity until I kill it using the System Monitor in Ubuntu.

This problem never happened until I added Scala to my Java project. Note, I'm not compiling Scala code - just including jars that were compiled with scala and I'm including the Scala compiler/library jars as part of the classpath.

Basically, Maven will run a bunch of tests and then hang:

```
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.206 sec
Running jobprep.domain.student.ActiveQuestionTests
Tests run: 26, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.065 sec
Running jobprep.domain.sysadmin.WebpageValidationTests
Tests run: 4, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.225 sec
Running jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests
```

When it comes to OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests, it freezes. It would appear that the reason why is that OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer is using @Configurable. If I comment out the test class and run the tests again, it'll just freeze on the next test class that uses @Configurable.

**EDIT**: It's interesting enough, if I tell maven to just run the tests in the "jobprep.domain.question.openended" package, it works 100%. If I tell it to run everything in "jobprep.domain", it still works! If I tell it to run everything in "jobprep", then the problem happens.

Is there something I should be aware of with Scala, AspectJ, Spring, etc. when it comes to this root package?

In Maven, if I tell surefire to load only a subset of my tests, it works. 893 out of the 1096 tests in my test suite will **run** and **pass**. This isn't perfect though because I need to get the remaining tests to work still:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.8.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/dao/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/domain/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/domain/**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/service/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/service/**/*Tests.java</include>
            <include>**/validator/*Tests.java</include>
        </includes>
        <excludes>
            <exclude>**/Abstract*Tests*.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/DatabaseTests.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/ControllerTests.java</exclude>
            <exclude>**/ValidationTests.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

It sucks that I have to be this fine-grained, but I don't know any other way to go about solving this problem.

Anyway, once I add this line, it starts to lock up at the OpenEndedSubmissionDeserializerTests like before:

```
<include>**/controllers/*Tests.java</include>
```

You know what's curious though? If I run the tests for controllers *only*, it works! Bloody hell! Could this mean they both run separately, but not together?!?

Anyway, when maven frezes, if I press CTRL-\ in linux instead of CTRL-C, this is what happens:

```
"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190cb1e800 nid=0x77d in Object.wait() [0x00007f191015b000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f191b06e4b8> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
    - locked <0x00007f191b06e4b8> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c7fb800 nid=0x77c in Object.wait() [0x00007f191025c000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f191b06e4b8> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)
    at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:534)
    - locked <0x00007f191b06e4b8> (a com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner)

"Timer-0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190d396800 nid=0x77b in Object.wait() [0x00007f191035d000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f191b073aa8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:509)
    - locked <0x00007f191b073aa8> (a java.util.TaskQueue)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)

"Low Memory Detector" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c025800 nid=0x740 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread1" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c023000 nid=0x73f waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"CompilerThread0" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c020000 nid=0x73e waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c01e000 nid=0x73d waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000040c03800 nid=0x73c in Object.wait() [0x00007f19119e8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f19181046f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:118)
    - locked <0x00007f19181046f8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:134)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:159)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=10 tid=0x0000000040c01000 nid=0x73b in Object.wait() [0x00007f1911ae9000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00007f1918104670> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:485)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:116)
    - locked <0x00007f1918104670> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040b78800 nid=0x735 waiting on condition [0x00007f193bc5e000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00007f191d8b6a58> (a java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch$Sync)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:158)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.parkAndCheckInterrupt(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:811)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:969)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1281)
    at java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch.await(CountDownLatch.java:207)
    at org.hsqldb.lib.CountUpDownLatch.await(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.executeCompiledStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00007f191d8b6358> (a org.hsqldb.Session)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.fetchResult(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.executeQuery(Unknown Source)
    - locked <0x00007f19313c0b70> (a org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:208)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1869)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:718)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:270)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadEntity(Loader.java:1953)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.AbstractEntityLoader.load(AbstractEntityLoader.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3270)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:496)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:477)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:227)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:269)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:152)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1080)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:997)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:990)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate$1.doInHibernate(HibernateTemplate.java:519)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.doExecute(HibernateTemplate.java:406)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.executeWithNativeSession(HibernateTemplate.java:374)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:512)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTemplate.get(HibernateTemplate.java:506)
    at jobprep.dao.BaseDaoSupport.find(BaseDaoSupport.java:65)
    at jobprep.dao.BaseDaoSupport.mandatoryFind(BaseDaoSupport.java:69)
    at jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer.parseActiveQuestion(OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer.java:42)
    at jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer.deserialize(OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer.java:30)
    at jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests.deserialize(OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests.java:44)
    at jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests.deserializeWithNoText(OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializerTests.java:24)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:82)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:240)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:180)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.junit4.JUnit4TestSet.execute(JUnit4TestSet.java:59)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.executeTestSet(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:115)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.suite.AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.execute(AbstractDirectoryTestSuite.java:102)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.Surefire.run(Surefire.java:180)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.runSuitesInProcess(SurefireBooter.java:350)
    at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.SurefireBooter.main(SurefireBooter.java:1021)

"VM Thread" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040bfc800 nid=0x73a runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040b8b800 nid=0x736 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040b8d800 nid=0x737 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040b8f000 nid=0x738 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=10 tid=0x0000000040b91000 nid=0x739 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=10 tid=0x00007f190c028800 nid=0x741 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 1517

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 126336K, used 74112K [0x00007f192d220000, 0x00007f19378c0000, 0x00007f1937cc0000)
  eden space 82880K, 88% used [0x00007f192d220000,0x00007f19319620d0,0x00007f1932310000)
  from space 43456K, 2% used [0x00007f1932310000,0x00007f193242e040,0x00007f1934d80000)
  to   space 41728K, 0% used [0x00007f1935000000,0x00007f1935000000,0x00007f19378c0000)
 PSOldGen        total 278464K, used 184803K [0x00007f1917cc0000, 0x00007f1928cb0000, 0x00007f192d220000)
  object space 278464K, 66% used [0x00007f1917cc0000,0x00007f1923138df8,0x00007f1928cb0000)
 PSPermGen       total 86016K, used 57644K [0x00007f19128c0000, 0x00007f1917cc0000, 0x00007f1917cc0000)
  object space 86016K, 67% used [0x00007f19128c0000,0x00007f191610b3c8,0x00007f1917cc0000)
```

Here's the aop.xml:

```
<aspectj>
    <weaver options="-showWeaveInfo -XmessageHandlerClass:org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJWeaverMessageHandler">
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.finite.FiniteStudentSubmissionDeserializer"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedQuestion"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedResult"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.openended.OpenEndedStudentSubmissionDeserializer"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.category.CategoryStudentSubmissionDeserializer"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.question.fill.FillInTheBlankStudentSubmissionDeserializer"/>
        <include within="jobprep.domain.keywords.GroupedKeywords"/>
    </weaver>
</aspectj>
```

Here's the maven plugin to get aspectj to work, which I know actually works because it's been working for a really long time:

```
        <!-- AspectJ -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>test-compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <complianceLevel>1.6</complianceLevel>
                <aspectLibraries>
                    <aspectLibrary>
                        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
                    </aspectLibrary>
                </aspectLibraries>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Can I get some help with this? What information do I need to give you guys?

I am scared to build this project and deploy to the server even though all the tests work in the IDE... because if the Aspects/AOP is locking up in tests, it probably doesn't work if I were to build and package the project using maven.

Comment: okay, i added a pile more code

Comment: Have you added the scala compiler to the build tag in the pom file?

Comment: @abhin4v: I could, but it wouldn't matter because there are no scala class files to compiler. They are already compiled from other projects. I have tried this "for the heck of it", and it did nothing :(

Comment: So let me get this straight, there are no scala files, scala compiler is not added in the build config, only scala libs are added as dependency. And this error does not occur when you remove the scala dependencies. Right?

Comment: @abhin4v: I'm assuming it would, but it's now i'm possible to get rid of the scala dependencies to be 100% sure, because I spent an entire day coding functionality that now depends on them. I can't just disable the project's dependency and have it compile now :( I guess I could break a bunch of tests to be sure. I may as well do that.

Comment: @abhin4v: Yeah, actually I did "hg update -r xx" to go back and all the tests run fine before the scala additions.

Comment: Okay, I verified it - scala's the problem. I remove scala from the test class path and the compile class path, and everything works again. ARGH!@!@!

Answer (score 2):

Does your @Configurable type extends a Scala class? If you can post sample code (or ideally a simple Maven project) that shows how your @Configurable classes and Scala classes interact, that will help resolve it.

Comment: Nope... all of the @Configurable stuff is pure Java. In fact, it used to work 100% before I decided to use Scala for a minor aspect of the project. This is not a new project, but an existing one.

Comment: In that case, it is hard to see how using a Scala jar affects @Configurable. I guess the only way to really figure this out is for you to create a separate small project and see if you can reproduce it. If you can, please share and I will take a look.

Comment: One quick thing to try: Use 1.2 version of AspectJ maven plugin. I have experienced issues with 1.3.

Comment: @ramnivas: Okay, let me try lowering the version ;) If that doesn't work, I will try and do this in a new project like you suggested. The source isn't open though, so it's not cool to give it out.

Comment: @ramnivas: Nope, 1.2 does the same thing :( I updated the top post if you care to read more info. This is so annoying. This definitely has to be the worst problem I've run into in a very long time.

Comment: I don't need (or want!) your source code, but rather a small made-up representative that exhibits the problem. Can you also try removing the Scala jar to make sure that that is indeed the source of the problem and not something else?

Comment: @Ramnivas +1 for being the author of one of my favorite books :-)

Comment: @seanizer. Thanks and I am delighted to have readers like you.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is YES, aspectj is interfering with scala classes.  Note that Scala has many inner and outer classes, and aspectj is apparently [not terribly bright about determining what the outer class is](http://coffeesgone.wordpress.com/2009/11/06/scala-anger-aspectj-an-intervention-was-in-order/).

Try adding

```
  <weaver>
    <exclude>scala..*</exclude>
  </weaver>
```

To your aop.xml file and see what happens.